# Yellow exclamation triangle on solution file of project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have made a solution containing different projects in Visual Studio 2013. It was working fine but today I am seeing yellow exclamation triangle on solution file and some of project folders. When I am trying to open the solution in Visual studio, its giving me error.

**The selected file is not a valid solution file**

I have searched on web about this issue. I did not find anything fruitful. 
Any help?

Comment: Your solution file is corrupt, this can often be caused by source control conflicts.  Edit the file in a text editor to see if you can spot the problem.

Comment: Yes i have removed the source control conflicts but still exclamation.